# How to force log off for User.Identity.Name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, identity, membership-provider, membership

My application is retrieving the wrong identity. It's taking my OS name rather than my web application user name. I've tried to set a new identity with the following code, but it still grabs my OS account name.

```
If User.Identity.Name = "DOMAIN\Name" Then
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
        HttpContext.Current.User = New GenericPrincipal(New GenericIdentity(String.Empty), Nothing)
    End If
```

I would like to forcefully log off from `User.Identity.Name` because every time I boot, the name is wrong. Can I build my web application with the default name as null, until I login through the application?

I've tried to reboot my desktop, but the name still is taken from my OS identity. How can I make it stop!!!

Note: the way the user name was set, was I got a pop up that prompted me my user name and password for the OS account, but the website shouldn't do that. It was OS verification. Now I need that to be detached.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="Welcome.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="20" name=".Auth" protection="All">
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

Comment: If it's getting your username from your PC\Domain.. then this isn't forms authentication, so the formsauthentication.signout probably won't help.  This may be related instead to the hosting of the application in IIS, it's probably set to windows authentication.. correct?

Comment: @weitknows Mode is set to forms on web.config, i've updated my issue.

Comment: @GivenPie Are you currently debugging this application with Visual Studio in your local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have Windows Authentication disabled in IIS?

[image: Windows Authentication Disabled]

Comment: i came back to revisit this issue and... your right. iis settings has windows authentication and anonymous off. Had to change that and it worked.